# What does "jam the speeders" mean, and is this used successfully in any other Star Wars media?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *The Rise of Skywalker*, there's a point where Resistance fighters are performing an assault along the surface of a Star Destroyer, and Admiral Pryde reacts by telling a crew member to "jam the speeders". The crew member states that the Resistance members aren't using speeders, and it's revealed that they're riding horse-like animals for their assault.

Is there any explanation of what "jam the speeders" actually means, or what it would achieve, in any other *Star Wars* media (Legends *or* canon)?  Particularly, is there any example of it being used *successfully* at any point?

Comment: Closest I've found is that the new First Order Speederbike toys (https://www.marianos.com/p/hasbro-star-wars-galaxy-of-adventures-first-order-driver-and-treadspeeder-toy/0063050986765) claim that they're built in a way that prevents traditional methods of jamming speederbikes.

Comment: Sadly, this seems to be nothing more than a very poor attempt at lip service to explain why the resistance is using animals in their attack.

Comment: Did somebody say "[jammed](https://youtu.be/rGvblGCD7qM)"?

Answer (score 5):

In *Return of the Jedi*, Luke tells Leia to

> Jam their comlink. Center switch!
>
> <sub>[*Return of the Jedi* script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html)</sub>

while Luke and Leia are chasing scout troopers on speeder bikes in order to prevent the scout troopers from sending a radio message that rebels are on the forest moon of Endor. This is a form of [radio jamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_jamming).